# Giving a value to a href in a anchor tag with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Sounds dumb but I can't find a way to pass a variable data defined in the href:

ComponentFile.vue
I tried all of those:

```
<a href=" url ">{{ url }}</a>
<a href=" {{ url }}">{{ url }}</a>
<a href=" {{ url }}">{{ url }}</a>
<a v-bind:href="url">{{ url }}</a>
<a @click=" url " v-bind:href="url"> {{ url }}</a>


...
export default {
        data() {
                   url: 'http://anywhere.com'
  }
}
```

What is the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've defined `data()` as a function, but it isn't returning anything.  It should return an object with the data like so:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            url: 'http://anywhere.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Then either of these will work:

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{ url }}</a>
<a v-bind:href="url">{{ url }}</a>
```

EDIT FOR VUE 2:

Interpolating variables in attributes is no longer recommended.  Change:

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{ url }}</a>
```

To one of these:

```
<a :href="url">{{ url }}</a>
<a v-bind:href="url">{{ url }}</a>
```

Comment: How do I do concatenation with a string.

Comment: <a id="aEmailAddress" v-bind:href="'mailto:' + Email"> gave me <a id="aEmailAddress" href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.xxx">

Comment: for vitepress `<a v-bind:href="url">{{ url }}</a>` worked fine. first way didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="app">
   <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a>
</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app', // Vue.js will just work inside the div with id of app
    data: {
      url: 'http://anywhere.com' 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

realy simple:

```
<a :href="'mailto:' + email">{{email}}</a>
```